# Formality of "that thought is not worthy of you"

Tags: phrase-usage, usage, formality

Some time ago I learned the phrase "that thought is not worthy of you." My understanding is that this means roughly: "by expressing that thought, you are degrading yourself."

My question: is this phrase a particularly formal or informal one? Would it be out of place, say, in an academic debate between two professors? or in an informal chat between two friends?

Comment: *Of course* it would be out of place in academic debate between two professors - it's incredibly *rude / belittling / dismissive / judgemental!*

Comment: No it isn't. It's very polite. It's saying "you expressed an unfortunate opinion, but I know you're better than that."

Comment: I've known professors who *were* rude, belittling, dismissive *and* judgemental.

Comment: I recently heard it used in an episode of _Yes Minister_ (the minister uses it to criticize his permanent secretary), so I thought it can't be so rude that it would be out of place in that context. Unless that's why that line is funny?

Comment: It's similar to saying "I thought you were better than that“

Comment: Apart from one literary usage by Disraeli, and one "facetious" use in the *Yes, Minister* TV sitcom, I can't find any other instances of *[that] **thought** is not worthy of you*. But when I search for just ***is not worthy of you***, I notice that regardless of whatever the *specific* "unworthy" thing might be, it's often preceded by an "apologetic disclaimer" like ***Forgive me for saying, but...*** Which strongly implies ***any*** such assertion is potentially negative towards the addressee

Answer (score -1):

That saying is neither particularly formal nor particularly informal. It might be heard in an academic debate between two professors or in an informal chat between two friends. (However, keep in mind that in informal contexts it would be more common to contract "is not" to "isn't".)

Commenters expressed the opinion that the saying is both "incredibly rude" and "very polite". In fact, it can be either. It is more likely to be considered rude if the thought belongs to the audience and represents something that the audience has already thought or done. For example:

> A: My friend's English is so bad that I believe that he should never speak in public.
> B: That thought isn't worthy of you.

The thought belongs to person A, who says that he already believes it. Therefore, person B's statement is more likely to be considered rude.

> A: My friend thinks that my English is very bad and that I should study much more.
> B: That thought isn't worthy of you.

The thought does not belong to person A, who has presumably not accepted or acted upon it. Therefore, person B's statement is more likely to be considered polite.